# Is there a easy way to make a movement script for 2d unity game?

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

I need help with C# in Unity. I know C# pretty well but don't know the C# UnityEngine namespace.

Unity doesn't support enough movement script's for and since I don't know how to use C# for Unity, I don't want o try editing the main code.

Any code using this namespace I am confused with:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
```

and I am confused with variables like this:

```cs
public float speed = 6.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F; 
public float gravity = 20.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple 2d caracter movement controller. In order for this script to work, you must:

**1**. Assign this script to your caracter.

**2**. Add a RigidBody2d to your caracter.

**3**. Assign a value at the speed and jumpHeight variables from the inspector of your caracter.

```
public float speed;    
public float jumpHeight; 
Rigidbody2D rb; 

void Start(){
    //Get the rigidbody2d of the gameObject this script is assigned to.
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update() {
    //Determine the direction of the movement based on user input.
    float moveDir = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    //Calculate the velocity of the gameObject.
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDir * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    // Your jump code:
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you. If you need more help, check unity's official [turtorials](https://learn.unity.com/tutorials).